# Encrypt string in ios and android and decrypt the web service java

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, encryption

I have 3 applications, iOS (Objective-C), Android (Java) and Web service (Java). I need to send a String Json encrypted to the Web Service from mobile apps and decrypting this content on Web Service.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this so that the Web Service use the same algorithm to interpret data received from both platforms?

Thank you!

Comment: There is confusion in the question where it states: "Json encrypted". JSON is not encryption, it is encoding and supported on most platforms. Please clarify that you are just concerned with JSON and not encryption such as AES.

Answer (score 0):

Use a standard hashing algorithm such as MD5. This way the password will be the unknown key, and you will avoid having to expose it.